# Server-side model change event in DerbyJS 0.6

Tags: node.js, derbyjs, racerjs

In DerbyJS:

How do I add event listeners to "The Model", only server side, without having to rely on requests (express middleware)?

Related question I've found:
[How to create server-side application logic on Racer / DerbyJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641540/how-to-create-server-side-application-logic-on-racer-derbyjs)

Of course I can write an express middleware. But the "shared" data model would come in really handy if I could access it without having to rely on a request, and I don't know how to do that without having to put the specific code into the *shared codebase*.

## Use case: order processing for e-commerce software

My model could be like this:

```
{
  orders: [ {
    id: '1',
    products: [ ... ],
    user: [ ... ],
    token: 'stripe credit card token I get from Client here'
  }, {
    ...
  } ]
}
```

This way the client could place new orders doing

```
model.at('orders').add(myOrder);
```

And the server could process it by listening for `'insert'` events:

```
model.on('insert', 'orders', function(captures, index, newOrders) {
  newOrders.forEach(processOrder);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!! :)

You have 2 options.

**Option 1)**

Use app.serverUse to include a server side script, or use the store.js if you have used yo derby-generator. There you can :

```
var model = dbStore.createModel();
model.subscribe("orders", function(){
  model.on("insert", "orders.**", function() {
   ...
  });
});
```

**Option 2)**

Using https://github.com/derbyparty/derby-hook

```
dbStore.hook('create', 'orders', function(id, doc, session, backend) {
  var model = dbStore.createModel();
  var $order = model.at('orders.'+ id);
   ...
});
```

Comment: Actually, in the meantime I have tried both of those. Option 1 results in this: https://github.com/derbyjs/racer/issues/212 

Option 2 never fires the create event. 

I have worked around Option 1, getting it to work, if I subscribe to the model only after a 10 seconds timeout (after the server started). 

I'll still accept this anser as it is obviously the correct answer "by design".

Comment: I notice the error you get is related to redis, in my configuration I don't use redis. FYI I am using the latest alpha release of derby, 0.6-alpha41, maybe this helps

Comment: what does orders.** accomplish vs orders.* ?

Comment: "orders.*" listens to shallow (1 level deep) changes, "orders.**" listens to deep changes inside the orders path.